# como se soluciono el npm ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: nodejs, npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo solucioné creando manualmente la carpeta npm, sera lo correcto!

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Redáctala como tal.